# No such method applying pointcut in Spring AOP to batch job

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, aspectj

I'm learning Spring AOP, and decided to use it for some performance monitoring on a batch job. I want to monitor the execution times of a `jdbctemplate` object's `.update()` method within a **Spring Batch ItemWriter's** `write()` method.

The relevant parts of my **pom.xml**:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My **spring configuration XML file**:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="writerMethods" expression="execution(* my.package.name.writers.IvrWriter.write())"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="performanceMonitor" pointcut-ref="writerMethods" order="2"/>
</aop:config>
```

However, I'm receiving a **NoSuchMethodError** that I'm having some trouble understanding how to debug:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:880)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:852)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:446)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.resetAdviceMonitor(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.setBeanFactory(AbstractBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 27 more
```

I'm not even sure whether or not this is a dependency issue with Spring AOP, a syntax error in terms of how I am writing the pointcut expression, or something else. I have followed a tutorial accessed[enter link description here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial) here on how to write pointcut expressions. Can anyone direct me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from exception stacktrace:

> NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory.getSingletonMutex()Ljava/lang/Object;

you should update in your pom.xml version for  for spring aop afticat to version : **4.3.9.RELEASE** . You use two different version for spting artifacts **spring-aspects with 3.1.2.RELEASE** and **spring-aop with 4.3.9.RELEASE** they are not compatible

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

better use properties variable in pom.xml

```
<properties>
     <spring.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using spring-aop (4.3.4). I replaced this with spring-aop(4.0.5) , this solved my problem.